# iOS UITableView deleted section lingers in UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have UITableView with multiple sections created from a data model which can be updated/edited from outside the view.

The updates to the table view are done in viewWillAppear. Basically the data model is recreated and [tableview reloadData] is invoked.

So far I have not had any problems but with the following section I can't seem to understand what is going on. It lingers on even when it has been deleted from the data model and table view

Correct render

[image]

After deleting section

[image]

Comment: @Glorfindel thx for fixing the images!

Comment: solved it! the problem was cell instance issues. The cell with red background is supposed to be of a different cell instance but was being returned as a regular cell UITableViewCell instance.